# vis.js - how to place item in center of graph

Tags: vis.js

I have tree structure like next :

- id: 1

  - id: 2

    - id: 8
    - id: 9
    - id: 10
    - id: 11
    - id: 12
  - id: 3

    - id: 13
  - id: 4
  - id: 5
  - id: 6
  - id: 7
  - id: 8

And need to show it (as network graph, not as tree)
After page loading graph must be centered on `{id:1}` item.

How can I make it?

Comment: What effort did you put into trying this yourself? There is extensive docs and examples available for vis.js.

Comment: Thanks, I re-readed "network" docs and found docs about positioning. Strange, but previously i not found it ("x", "y" in "network"=>"nodes", I need to calculate only one node position, so it's mustn't be difficult)

Comment: ok great you found a solution!